# Pointers and variables in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct TCB_t *del = RunQ;
del->next = NULL;
```

In the line of code above any changes that are made to del are also made to RunQ.  In the first line all the values of RunQ are also given to del.  I figured after this line any changes to del would not effect RunQ.  However after the second line, RunQ->next is Null.  Why is this and what do I do so changes the I make to del do not effect RunQ

Comment: You may want to copy that object.

Comment: I would suggest you do some more reading on pointers, because you seem to be misunderstanding what they are. What you're observing is expected behavior.

Comment: pointers *point* to other things. The first line makes `del` point to the same object as `RunQ`.

Comment: @moooeeeep, yes I want to copy the object

Comment: Try `struct TCB_t del = *RunQ; del.next = NULL;`

Comment: Then please show us what you have tried to achieve this, and what is your actual problem/misunderstanding. Please be as specific as possible in your question.

Comment: If you want `del` to point to a new copy of the object, you have to copy it yourself: `memmove(del, RunQ, sizeof(*del));`. This will of course be a "shallow" copy. If you want a deep copy, you'll have to do that manually. C is a primitive language, it doesn't do these things for you.

Comment: None of the changes made to `del` are also made to `RunQ`. If we talk about their targets though...

Comment: No, in the above code, changes made to `del` are **not** made to `RunQ`.   However, changes made to the things being pointed to by `del` (e.g. `del->next`) are also made to the things being pointed to by `RunQ` (e.g. `RunQ->next`), since both of those pointers point to the same thing. Make sure you understand this point very clearly (a *pointer* is different to *the thing it points to*) as you have posted several questions in a row with the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct TCB_t del = *RunQ;
del.next = NULL;
```

or

```
struct TCB_t newRunQ = *RunQ;
struct TCB_t *del = &newRunQ;
del->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Make sure to read up on _deep copy_ vs. _shallow copy_ before adopting this.